# Laravel sharing data with all view then how can we manage this key in all our vue compoents?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am developing laravel with Vue application. In laravel i am using View::share('key', 'value'); so i am getting all key value in all blade files. But in vue components, I am not getting for this key for all Vue components.

Comment: You would need to ensure that you're passing this as a property. Otherwise, you would need to pass it as a `data-` attribute and apply the value yourself using `beforeMount`

Comment: But i need to pass globally so i can access in all my component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solved this issue.

> First of all create a translations service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TranslationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Cache::rememberForever('translations', function () {
            return collect([
                'php' => $this->phpTranslations(),
                'json' => $this->jsonTranslations(),
            ]);
        });
    }

    private function phpTranslations()
    {
        $path = resource_path('lang/' . App::getLocale());

        return collect(File::allFiles($path))->flatMap(function ($file) {
            $key = ($translation = $file->getBasename('.php'));

            return [$key => trans($translation)];
        });
    }

    private function jsonTranslations()
    {
        $path = resource_path('lang/' . app()->getLocale() . '.json');

        if (is_string($path) && is_readable($path)) {
            return json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
        }

        return [];
    }
}
```

> Register it in config/app.php file:

```
'providers' => [
    // your other providers
    App\Providers\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
],
```

> Then you have to pass translation strings to JS in blade template. I
>   did it in the default layouts/app.blade.php file:

```
<script>
    window._translations = {!! cache('translations') !!};
</script>
```

> Now you need some js function to retrieve translations and apply
>   replacements. To do that I have created a trans.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    methods: {
        /**
         * Translate the given key.
         */
        __(key, replace) {
            let translation, translationNotFound = true

            try {
                translation = key.split('.').reduce((t, i) => t[i] || null, window._translations.php)
                if (translation) {
                    translationNotFound = false
                }
            } catch (e) {
                translation = key
            }

            if (translationNotFound) {
                translation = window._translations.json[key]
                    ? window._translations.json[key]
                    : key
            }

            _.forEach(replace, (value, key) => {
                translation = translation.replace(':' + key, value)
            })

            return translation
        }
    },
}
```

> And the last step is to include the method as a mixin:

```
Vue.mixin(require('./trans'))
```

> That's it. Now you can use translations in Vue components like so:

```
<template>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Example Component') }}</div>

    <div class="card-body">
        {{ __("I'm an example component.") }}
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.__('Component mounted.'))
    }
}
</script>
```